# Is it advisable to remove Evince (Default Document Viewer)?

Tags: pdf, evince

I installed qpdfview and liked it more than Evince. So I want to remove Evince. Is it advisable (as it is a core item in Ubuntu 14.04)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the program *Evince* was installed on your system as a component of the *ubuntu-desktop* metapackage. There are several excellent answers here about what a metapackage is and the implications of uninstalling a component of a metapackage and the metapackage itself. Here are two:

[What is the difference between a meta-package and a package?](https://askubuntu.com/a/66268/248158)
[How to determine if a package is a meta-package from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/193386/248158)

Coming back to your case, if you run `apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop` and examine the output, you'll see a section called **Depends:**. This lists all the software, including Evince, specified by the ubuntu-desktop metapackage. If you attempt to uninstall *any* of the packages in that list, the ubuntu-desktop metapackage will also be uninstalled (along with other dependencies unique to the package you want to uninstall in the first place).

Going further down, you'll see this:

```
Description-en: The Ubuntu desktop system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu desktop system
 .
 It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, so it is recommended that
 it not be removed.
```

In other words, sometime in the future, when you want to upgrade your system to the next permissible version of Ubuntu, the upgrade process will want to refer to the ubuntu-desktop metapackage. At that time, it will be advisable that you re-install ubuntu-desktop before undertaking the upgrade step. Until that time, not having ubuntu-desktop on your system doesn't mean you'll be without a "desktop"; its absence has no adverse day-to-day consequences.

As a precaution, the next time you want to uninstall anything, run a simulation first by leaving out `sudo` and by including `-s`. For a really scary simulation, look at the output of `apt-get purge -s zenity`. Then, if you have doubts, you could research the matter as you did for Evince!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a secondary program it does not matter. To remove it simply Press CTRL+ALT+T this will open the console. In there run this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge evince
```

Thanks, hope this helps.

Comment: It gave a warning that it is a core item and removing it may cause future upgrades to be incomplete.And the item shown in the warning message was Ubuntu Desktop System.

Comment: Well in that case I would just suggest leaving it, its not that big of a deal, the file is small enough.